# SBT is loading project definition from wrong location

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

When starting SBT I see

```
Loading project definition from /Users/shruti/.sbt/0.13/staging/0156a9e3df5385400375/xyz/project
```

which is not where my project is located. (I wouldn't care, but the changes I make are not being reflected in this copy.) I searched my entire project but this path is not defined or written anywhere, neither in scalaopts. A grep over all files doesn't work either.

Does anybody know where this path is defined or how to change it?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you load your project? Does your actual project have any source dependencies (`ProjectRef` or `RootProject`)?

Comment: Not that I know of. The loading project part comes when I start sbt, I don't load it explicitly.

Anyway, It probably doesn't have anything to do with sbt, because I uninstalled and reinstalled it but the problem remained. It was when I cloned the project to a different folder that problem got fixed. 

But I'll leave the question here, because I'd like to know why the path changed. I didn't make any changes to the build.sbt or configuration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sbt uses the staging area when the folder containing the project is not read/write. Making the project folder read/write should fix this.